# How can I change the Style of a WPF TabControl's ItemTemplate so that I can set the Tab Headers' Background color?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am using the WPF TabControl's ItemTemplate property to bind the content of each TabItem's header. I am also using the ItemContainerStyle property to set the TabItem's content to a dynamically selected user control.  This method is working 100% as expected, but I am having trouble now with styling the TabControl's header.

I set the background property of the TabControl to black:

```
<TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs.Tabs}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Tabs.SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ReadyForInput}"
        Background="Black"
        x:Name="MainTab">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">                      
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding TabHeader}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter
                    Property="Content"
                    Value="{Binding TabContentControl}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

This results in:
[The TabItem has a black background, but the header stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXNIA.png)

If I set the background color of the StackPanel in the ItemTemplate, I'm left with [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1kGl.png)

How can I change the background color (style) of the TabItems' header when the TabControl is bound as I have it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Background` property of the `StackPanel` in the `ItemTemplate` to black?

Comment: Yes, that works, but it only sets the background of the stack panel.  There is still some margin left between the Header and StackPanel, so it doesn't fully set the background color of the Tab's header.

Comment: I've updated my question with another image when trying your suggestion, @Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Background property in your ItemContainerStyle:

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContentControl}" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Changing the background colour of the selected tab requires more effort. You need to override the ControlTemplate of the TabItem. You can copy the default template into your XAML markup by right-clicking on a TabItem in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy and then edit it as per your requirements:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs.Tabs}" Background="Black" x:Name="MainTab">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#E5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#ECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Border" Color="#7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Border" Color="#D9D9D9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="Black"/>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                        Text="header..."
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContentControl}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                                <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: That worked. Now I just have to figure out how to cleanly turn that into a themeable style.  Thank you!